# Confirming the difference between import * and from xxx import *

Tags: python, python-import

I was surprised to find out that

```
import foo
```

and

```
from foo import *
```

had different effects on global members.  I wanted to confirm that my experiments are the correct behavior.

In the first example, changing a member in module foo will reflect in all code that imports foo.  However, changing that member in the later case only seems to affect the file into which it was imported.  In other words, using the later approach will give each importing file its own copy of the members from foo.

the behavior i want is to have access to foo.x from all files, be able to change it from all files, and have that change reflected in all files ( a true global if you will).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, your observations are correct. This is a consequence of the way that binding works in Python.

When one does

```
import foo
```

then `foo` becomes a global name that references the module `foo`. When one does

```
foo.bar = 7
```

Then the reference is followed and the object `foo` is loaded. Then `7` is stored in the `bar` attribute.

When another module imports `foo`, it just pulls the object out of `sys.modules['foo']` and gets the modified value.

When one does

```
from foo import bar
```

`globals()['bar']` is set to reference `foo.bar`. When one later does

```
 bar = 7
```

`globals()['bar']` no longer references `foo.bar` but references a copy of `7`. That is, the original binding in the global scope of the importing module is simply replaced.

In the fist example, one is modifying attributes of an object that is stored in `sys.modules` and will be common to all modules that have imported it. In the second example, one is modifying the global scope of the importing module.

If one was to do something along the lines of

```
 from foo import fobaz
 fobaz.foobar = 7
```

Then that change *would* be propagated to other importing modules because one is not *overwriting* the global reference but *following* it to modify an attribute of the object that it points to. So essentially, you should be able to modify mutable objects so long as you don't overwrite the global binding.

I think that something like this is the closest that you are going to be able to cleanly get to a true global in python. As a language, it greatly values namespaces.

Answer (score 4):

Considering that global variables are generally considered to be a bad thing, I suspect a "true global" variable would be an exceedingly bad thing.

One other way to get similar behavior is to use class-scope attributes in a singleton object, and just import that. Then it is clearer where you are getting the "global" variable from.