# What is the difference between import httplib and from httplib import *?

Tags: python, module, httplib

I would like to know which is the difference between 
import httplib and 
from httplib import * 
By the way i am using python 2.73.

Comment: possible duplication of [Confirming the difference between import * and from xxx import *](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436401/confirming-the-difference-between-import-and-from-xxx-import)

Answer (score 0):

With `import httplib`, you would have to do

```
httplib.HTTPConnection(host)
```

With `from httplib import *`, you could do

```
HTTPConnection(host)
```

It is considered better to specify what you are importing in the second method, as in `from httplib import HTTPConnection`

Comment: It's preference, but if you use the `from` method, it's best to specify what you are importing instead of using the `*` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the different, by example:

```
>>> import httplib
>>> SEE_OTHER
NameError: name 'SEE_OTHER' is not defined
>>> httplib.SEE_OTHER
303

>>> from httplib import *
>>> SEE_OTHER
303
>>> httplib.SEE_OTHER
NameError: name 'httplib' is not defined
```

---

The `from httplib import *` is almost* never what you want, except possibly while experimenting with `httplib` in the interactive prompt.

Sometimes you want to import a few names out of a library—but in that case, specify the names explicitly:

```
from httplib import SEE_OTHER, MOVED_PERMANENTLY
```

---

Both import the module, but the former creates a single new name, `httplib`, in your current globals, while the latter instead copies all of the globals from `httplib` into your current globals.**

---

* "Almost" because there are a few good use cases even in scripts. For example, the idiomatic way to provide a Python implementation of a module with C accelerators is to end the Python script `foo.py` with `from _foo import *`.

** This isn't quite true, because of `__all__` and various other details, but close enough for now.