# Difference between importing from something and importing something?

Tags: python, pandas

So, recently I was studying Pandas and frequently we use this

```
import pandas as pd
```

and I was asked not to import it as

```
from pandas import *
```

Can someone explain the difference between these two approaches?

Comment: See, http://stackoverflow.com/q/710551 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/4436401

Comment: Thank you so much for these links.